# Jquery Chat Box - Show first messages at bottom of DIV moving up

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a Chat DIV that sends and receives messages.

Currently messages start at the top of the DIV and work down the DIV (shown in red) and when they hit the bottom they are pushed upwards with Jquery like below:

```
.scrollTop(activeConversationsDIV[0].scrollHeight);
```

[image]

I wanted to ask if there is method to start the messages at the bottom of the DIV? This would make more sense to a user as they would see what they are typing close to where they type it.

Is there a way to start the flow of messages from the bottom of the DIV working upwards?

thankyou

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `display: table`, `display: table-cell` and `vertical-align: bottom`.

Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/ktpRK/

CSS

```
#chat {
    display: table;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.chatMessage {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="chat">
<div class="chatMessage">
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test 2</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: and when you have 2 messages?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with positioning

HTML

```
<div id="chatbox">
    <div id="chatmessages">
        <div>Hi </div>
        <div>Hello </div>
        <div>How are you ?</div>
        <div>I am fine, Thanks ! </div>
        <div>And how about you? </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#chatbox {
    overflow:   none;
    position:   relative;
    width:      100%;
    height:     200px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
#chatmessages
{
    overflow:   auto;
    position:   absolute;
    bottom:     0;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 200px;
}
#chatmessages div {
    border:1px solid #e2e4e3;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin:5px;
    padding:10px;
}
```

JQuery

```
$('#chatmessages').scrollTop($('#chatmessages')[0].scrollHeight);
```

[jsfiddle with scroll](https://jsfiddle.net/ajiths4u/u9dzyvct/)

[jsfiddle without scroll](https://jsfiddle.net/ajiths4u/u9dzyvct/8/)